# What is the name for my endpoint port in cxf.conf

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm configuring cxf signing with the following example:

```
                <jaxws:client name="{http://cxf.apache.org}MyPortName" createdFromAPI="true">
                     <jaxws:properties>
                          <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="interop.client.KeystorePasswordCallback" />
                          <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="etc/client.properties" />
                          <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="etc/service.properties" />
                          <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="servicekeyalias" />
                     </jaxws:properties>
                </jaxws:client>
```

see: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

i need to set the name correctly according to the footnote:

```
For the jaxws:client's name attribute above, use the namespace of the WSDL along 
with the name attribute of the desired wsdl:port element under the WSDL's service
section. (See here and here for an example.)
```

the example don't work.

so my question is what should the name be? where can i find this in my wsdl and/or in my generated code?

is there a way to verify that the cxf.xml file is loaded?

i'm doing this because i get this error:

```
PolicyException: Security configuration could not be detected. Potential cause: Make sure jaxws:client element with name attribute value matching endpoint port is defined as well as a ws-security.signature.properties element within it.
```

and i see in the code that this (from the abstractBindingBuilder):

```
(String)message.getContextualProperty(userNameKey);
```

is giving null as a result.

well any help would be great!

Comment: Could you fix the problem?

Comment: it was a long time ago but below was what i then thought was the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

After generation of the java code from the wsdl you will have a file extening the service.
in the file is a Qname of the port this is what is needed.

name="{namespace}name"